# How to Loop Through Excel Rows in R to Use Rows in Code?

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have a CSV file with 20,000 latitude/longitude coordinates. E.g. a sample:

```
lat    lon
13.2   100.3
12.3   90.2
24.2   78.8

library(googleway)

google_streetview(
  location = c(13.2, 100.3), # lat/lon coordinates
  size = c(600, 400) # image size
```

Basically, I want the code above to use the lat/lon coordinates from the first row in the CSV file (which returns a Google Street View image of those coordinates), then loop back through the code and replace the lat/lon coordinates with the second line of the CSV file, and so on.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **purrr** package. Saying your csv is called **data**:

```
MyFunction <- function(lat, long){
 google_streetview(location = c(lat,long), size = c(600, 400))
}

purrr::map2(data$lat, data$long, MyFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you save the images that are outputted to a folder on my hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the looping functions to iterate over `lat` and `lon` values.

For example, using `Map` -

```
result <- Map(function(x, y) 
    google_streetview(location = c(x, y), size = c(600, 400)), df$lat, df$lon)
```